# 3 points blue, red, green form a triangle $T$ in $\mathbb R^2$. 3 points B, R, G inside that triangle. Do all proper rainbow triangles cover $T$?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, recreational-mathematics, coloring, convex-geometry

Suppose I have 3 points colored blue, red, and green resp. forming a triangle $T$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Suppose I have 3 more points colored blue, red, green resp. (possibly overlapping) in the interior of $T$. A rainbow triangle is one whose vertices are all different colors. A proper rainbow triangle is one properly contained within $T$.

> **Conjecture ($d=2$):** the union of all proper rainbow triangles covers (the interior of) $T$.

More generally, suppose I have $d+1$ points colored distinct colors $c_1,\ldots, c_{d+1}$ resp. forming a $d$-simplex $T$ in $\mathbb R^d$. Suppose I have $d+1$ more points colored $c_1,\ldots, c_{d+1}$ resp. (possibly overlapping) in the interior of $T$. A rainbow simplex is one whose vertices are all different colors. A proper rainbow simplex is one properly contained within $T$.

> **Conjecture:** the union of all proper rainbow simplices covers (the interior of) $T$.

---

For $d=2$, I drew some pictures and am convinced of its truth. But I only have a decent proof in the case that none of the sub/proper rainbow simplices overlap:

[image: triangles with colored vertices geometry problem]

In this case, every rainbow $(d-1)$-dimensional interior face (i.e. every line segment between 2 different colored points lying in the interior of $T$) has exactly 2 rainbow $d$-simplices having it as a face; so the outward normals point in opposite directions.

So when we add simplices together, all the interior faces cancel, leaving only the faces on the boundary of $T$, since those are the only ones that only have 1 $d$-simplex containing it as a face.

Thus, when we add up all the proper rainbow $d$-simplices, the resulting boundary is the boundary of $T$. I'm not sure how to 100% rigorously conclude that the sum must be exactly $T$, but still this seems like mostly the right route.

---

P.S. I came across this conjecture while working on a proof of the [strong Caratheodory theorem](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/colorful-caratheodory-revisited/). The proof of that linked in the linked blog post uses topology, so I've been trying to find a proof **using tools as elementary as possible**.

Comment: For $d=2$, if the interior points are arranged such that the proper rainbow triangles overlap, they still can be drawn, and will continue to cover the entire interior of the large triangle. It seems likely this is best shown by twisting the interior triangle CW or CCW.

Comment: @EricSnyder yes, I saw this when I drew out a bunch of cases. Showing this rigorously, and in a manner that extends to higher dimensions is challenging.

Comment: Gotcha. Alas, higher dimensions are a bit beyond my ability to imagine. It seems to me that this works in 3D, but anything bigger and my mind fails. Rigorous proof is definitely difficult though. I *think* that a rigorous geometric proof in 2D would involve the base case you show, the case where the inner points are arranged such that three of the triangles disappear, and the case where they reappear. I'll have to post a partial answer to show diagrams.

Comment: Will moving to higher dimensions be using Triangular Prisms (Are you planning to have only the surfaces populated or the interior of the prism as well? Will a tetrahedron include an internal tetrahedron as in the 2D case? Only internal tetrahedron?

Comment: @EricSnyder after asking friends, I now know a proof using a bit of topology (the fact that a continuous map from a closed ball in $\mathbb R^d$ to itself, that restricts to the identity on the boundary, must be surjective. This can be proven using the Brouwer fixed point theorem, which can in turn be proven using the combinatorial Sperner's lemma). The idea is to map from the "simple" case I drew above to the general case, by mapping between the interior points of the same colors, and extending to a map on the whole simplex by mapping convex combinations to convex combs. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Moti in 3D for instance, I will have a tetrahedron with vertices colored 4 different colors (say red, blue, green, yellow), and then inside that "outer" tetrahedron, I will have another 4 points (resp. red, blue, green yellow), for a total of 8 points.

Comment: So, each node is connected to 6 other nodes. For 4d it will be ...

Comment: @D.R. Gotcha! I was thinking some and it seemed it ought to be much easier than I was initially thinking, since other than crossing a point over a segment the octahedral net should always cover the triangle, including degenerate positions. I'll have to look at the theorems you mention. Thanks!

Comment: @Moti I think for 4D, you have a $4$-simplex inside another $4$-simplex, each with five points, and each node connected to eight others (all points not of the same color).